# ElasticSearch result get HITS count based on each word in the searchquery

Tags: elasticsearch

As we can see in the below simple ElasticSearch for text "Baby Oil" I get HIT-TOTAL of 8616.
Is there a way I can get the  HITs in details like below . Technically I want permutation of hit count for all words in search.

HIT TOTAL of 8618

HIT BABY of 5000

HIT OIL of 3618

HIT BABY AND OIL of 4500

[image]

**Update**

After using the "fielddata": true , we get the count for all the keywords, instead of keywords used in the search

[image]

Comment: You could, using 

"aggs": {
    "occurance": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "rawtext"
      }
    }
  }

But you have to change mappings and set fielddata to true on rawtext first.

Comment: @LeBigCat after your recommendation we see all Keywords ,  instead of the search , is there a way to get only Search input terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html)

> A multi-bucket aggregation where each bucket contains the documents that match a query.

**Query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "rawtext",
      "query": "baby oil"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "count": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "baby": {
            "match": {
              "rawtext": "baby"
            }
          },
          "oil": {
            "match": {
              "rawtext": "oil"
            }
          },
          "baby oil": {
            "match": {
              "rawtext":{
                "query": "baby oil",
                "operator": "and"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "count" : {
      "buckets" : {
        "baby" : {
          "doc_count" : 2
        },
        "baby oil" : {
          "doc_count" : 1
        },
        "oil" : {
          "doc_count" : 3
        }
      }
    }
  }
```